# How to add multiple values into a LinkedList serialize it to a text file in Java?

Tags: arrays, serialization, linked-list

My issue is that every time I submit information into the form it gets overwritten in the text instead of adding another set of information into the file.

Here is my main Class.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Main {

private JFrame frame;
public JTextField textField, textField_1, textField_2, textField_3;
public JButton btnSubmit, btnExit, btnAdmin;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main window = new Main();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Main() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(640, 480);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblInterestedMenSign = new JLabel("Interested Men Sign Up");
    lblInterestedMenSign.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 18));
    lblInterestedMenSign.setForeground(new Color(0, 204, 255));
    lblInterestedMenSign.setBounds(214, 37, 190, 60);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblInterestedMenSign);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("First Name");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblNewLabel.setForeground(new Color(0, 204, 255));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(49, 140, 113, 16);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Last Name");
    lblNewLabel_1.setForeground(new Color(0, 204, 255));
    lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(49, 183, 79, 16);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("E-Mail");
    lblNewLabel_2.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblNewLabel_2.setForeground(new Color(0, 204, 255));
    lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(49, 223, 56, 16);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("Phone Number");
    lblNewLabel_3.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblNewLabel_3.setForeground(new Color(0, 204, 255));
    lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(49, 265, 113, 16);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_3);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    textField.setBounds(174, 263, 190, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.setBounds(174, 221, 190, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    textField_2.setColumns(10);
    textField_2.setBounds(174, 181, 190, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_2);

    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    textField_3.setColumns(10);
    textField_3.setBounds(174, 138, 190, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_3);

    Submit s = new Submit();
    Exit e = new Exit();
    AdminPage a = new AdminPage();

    btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnSubmit.setBounds(49, 337, 97, 25);
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(s);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnSubmit);

    btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnExit.setBounds(230, 337, 97, 25);
    btnExit.addActionListener(e);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnExit);

    btnAdmin = new JButton("Admin");
    btnAdmin.setBounds(448, 337, 97, 25);
    btnAdmin.addActionListener(a);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAdmin);

    JLabel pic = new JLabel("");
    java.awt.Image img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/lsusheild1.jpg")).getImage();
    pic.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
    pic.setBounds(365, 97, 245, 227);
    frame.getContentPane().add(pic);

}

private class Submit implements ActionListener {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        try {
            //Create an array for collections to store information to a File
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            List person = new LinkedList();

            //String to connect information
            String first = textField.getText().toString();
            String last = textField_1.getText().toString();
            String email = textField_2.getText().toString();
            String phone = textField_3.getText().toString();


            //Store information from text fields.
            person.add(new Information(first, last, email, phone));             

            //Writes information to file
            new SerializationWrite(person);

            frame.dispose();
            Confirmation.Confirm();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class Exit implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private class AdminPage implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        frame.dispose();
        Admin.AdminLogin(); //admin login in page (another class)
    }
}
}
```

Here is the Information Class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Information implements Comparable<Information>, Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2450157020775629735L;
String firstname;
String lastname;
String phonenumber;
String email;


public Information(String firstname, String lastname,String phonenumber, String email) {
    super();
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    this.email = email;
}


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public String getPhonenumber() {
    return phonenumber;
}


public int compareTo(Information i) {

    int cmp = lastname.compareTo(i.lastname);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        cmp = firstname.compareTo(i.firstname);
    }       
    return cmp;
}


public String toString() { //to change from hash values to string values.
    return firstname + " - " + lastname + " - " + phonenumber + " - " + email;
}

}
```

Here is the SerializationWrite class

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class SerializationWrite {

public SerializationWrite(List<Information> person) {

    try {

        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Abraham\\Desktop\\Interest.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oo = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
        oo.writeObject(new Integer(person.size()));

        for (int i = 0; i < person.size(); i++) {
            oo.writeObject(person.get(i));
        }

        oo.close();
        fo.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

If you need anymore information just ask and I appreciate any help, I am sure it is simple but for some reason I just can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is some things that I have tried:

1) I tried increment the String variables (first, last, email, phone)
2) I added custom strings inside new information parameters and it did work.

What I discovered was that because the textFields do not change it will continue to overwrite the information placed in the textFields.

What do I do?